# Extract a list from a table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

If I set up an Excel table like so:
[matrix table with header row and column and cross selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQxs1.png)

What I like to do is to extract the values on the left column based on the "X" selection and the header row value.

So, for example, I enter "EC" in an entry cell and get result back of an array of {"Orange", "Grape"}, which presumable I can do further array operations on that result.

So, is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `FILTER` twice:

`=FILTER(A2:A5,FILTER(B2:E5,B1:E1=G1)="X")`

Comment: Ah, but I should specify I'm running Excel 2013...so may be not possible!

Comment: But I should also add, if I do this in GoogleSheet, it does have a similar Filter() function to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula solution for Excel 2013 and up,

In `H2`, enter array ("Ctrl"+"Shift"+"Enter") formula :

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5,N(IF(1,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$2:A$5)-ROW(A$1)/(INDEX(B$2:E$5,,MATCH(G2,B$1:E$1,0))<>""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTIF(INDEX(B$2:E$5,,MATCH(G2,B$1:E$1,0)),"?*")))))))
```

Then,

Highlighted `H2` formula cell >> Press **F9** >>

Will return >>

={"Orange";"Grape"}

And,

You can do further array operation on that formula cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With ***Microsoft 365*** you can try-

```
=FILTER(A2:A5,MMULT(--(B2:E5="X")*(B1:E1=G1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:E2))))
```

If you want to show result in single cell then use `TEXTJOIN()` function

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A2:A5,MMULT(--(B2:E5="X")*(B1:E1=G1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:E2)))))
```

If your version of excel support `BYROW()` then could try-

```
=FILTER(A2:A5,BYROW(B2:E5,LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(a="X")*(B1:E1=G1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, but I should specify I'm running Excel 2013...so may be not possible!

Comment: Possible but it will long formula. You need then `AGGREGATE()` function.